# How to dump data into a view?

Tags: php, laravel

I get a list of number and series. But when i dump data in to a view it appears like this:

> [{"id":1,"number":"e379079p272730","series":"88000000001","type":"import","group_series":null}]

I want on the view it will display the number value in the number column and the series value in the series column. But I don't know how to do that?

View admin.student.listcard

```html
<div class="card-block" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="card-title">
                <strong>Number</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="card-title">
                <strong>Series</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @foreach($orders as $order)
        <div class="row bottom">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     {{ $order->card }}
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">      
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

function

```php
public function listCard($studentId)
{
    $orders = Order::where('member_id',$studentId)->get();
    foreach($orders as $order){
        $order->card = Card::where('id',$order->card_id)->get();
    }
    return view('admin.student.listcard',compact('orders'));
}
```

Comment: Your look should be run over entire card block and you should extract and put data from ´$order->card´ and put in the appropriate places instead of the texts you have put on. I can't provide you with examples since I'm not familiar with this programming language but this is the basic idea you probably need to think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use eloquent relationships !

In your Order model :

```php
public function card()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Card::class);
}
```

In your controller :

```php
$orders = Order::with('card')->where('member_id',$studentId)->get();
```

In your view :

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
    <div class="row bottom">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ $order->card->number }}
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
             <div class="form-group">
                 {{ $order->card->series }}
             </div> 
         </div>
     </div>
@endforeach
```